# Erlang: difference between using gen_server:cast/2 and standard message passing

Tags: asynchronous, erlang, gen-server

I was working though a problem and noticed some code where a previous programmer was passing messages using the standard convention of PID ! Message. I have been using gen_server:cast/2. I was wondering if somebody could explain to me the critical differences and considerations when choosing between the two?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few minor differences:

- Obviously, the gen_server handles casts in `handle_cast` and "normal" messages in `handle_info`.
- A cast never fails; it always returns `ok`.  Sending a message with `!` fails with `badarg` if you are sending a message to an atom that is currently not registered by a process.  (Sending a message to a pid never causes an error, even if the process is dead.)
- If the gen_server is running on a remote node that is not currently connected to the local node, then `gen_server:cast` will spawn a background process to establish the connection and send the message, and return immediately, while `!` only returns once the connection is established.  (See the code for `gen_server:do_send`.)

As for when to choose one or the other, it's mostly a matter of taste.  I'd say that if the message could be thought of as an asynchronous API function for the gen_server, then it should use cast, *and* have a specific API function in the gen_server callback module.  That is, instead of calling `gen_server:cast` directly, like this:

```
gen_server:cast(foo_proc, {some_message, 42})
```

make a function call:

```
foo_proc:some_message(42)
```

and implement that function like the direct cast above.  That encapsulates the specific protocol of the gen_server inside its own module.

In my mind, "plain" messages would be used for events, as opposed to API calls.  An example would be monitor messages, `{'DOWN', Ref, process, Id, Reason}`, and events of a similar kind that might happen in your system.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to legoscia post I would say that it is easier to trace dedicated function API than messages. Especially in prod environment.