# When to use handle_info and handle_cast

Tags: erlang

It seems that the functionality of `gen_server:handle_cast/3` and `gen_server:handle_info/3` is very similar. I know that `handle_info/3` are used to handle timeout events.

Is there any other rule to use them? In my opinion, I prefer to use `handle_info/3` to handle async messages. As it is shorter to use the grammer sugar `!`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erlang: difference between using gen\_server:cast/2 and standard message passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968457/erlang-difference-between-using-gen-servercast-2-and-standard-message-passing)

Comment: @legoscia Yes, it's duplicate. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gen_server` is an abstraction over a typical process message loop. It provides you with API like `call` and `cast` to send messages to the process BUT as you also have the `PID` of the process, any code can send message to the process without going through the `call` or `cast` APIs and in those cases the `handle_info` callback is called. If you want to send messages to your process using the `!` operator then you probably don't need `gen_server` OR if you want to use `gen_server` then it is advised to use `call` and `cast` APIs for your server functionality and `handle_info` for other kind of messages.